# Where is the logger file in platform Ruby 2.7 on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-linux-2

My ruby application is running on platform Ruby 2.7 on Amazon Linux2.
The application create a logger by using below code:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'server.log'))
```

The application runs well, but the `server.log` file doesn't exist in `var/log`

I tried replace above code with below:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new('server.log')
```

Still cannot find `server.log` file. Can you please tell which directory the server.log will be in?

Comment: Where is `Rails.root`? In other words, which folder on this machine stores the rails project? `File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'server.log')` means exactly what it looks like: `/path/to/rails/application/log/server.log`.

Comment: I'm guessing the rails application does **not** live directly in `/var`. That would be very weird.

Comment: @TomLord Thanks Tom. If I want to put the logging file under /var/log/server.log, how should I modify the code?

Comment: `Rails.logger = Logger.new('/var/log/server.log')`??!

Comment: This would be an unusual choice, however; the `/var/log` folder is generally reserved for **system logs**, not application logs.